# Yii2 full calendar event filtering not working

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, fullcalendar, yii2-basic-app

I'm using Philipp Frenzel FullCalendar in Yii2 framework and its working perfectly. I want to implement basic filter events on calendar base on option select but my codes still not working. Help would be highly appreciated.

This is inside EventController :

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Event;
use app\models\EventSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * EventController implements the CRUD actions for Event model.
 */
class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Event models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        /*$searchModel = new EventSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);*/

        $events = Event::find()->all();
        $tasks = [];

        foreach ($events as $eve)
        {
              $event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
              $event->id = $eve->id;
              $event->backgroundColor = 'green';
              $event->title = $eve->title;
              $event->start = $eve->created_date;
              $tasks[] = $event;
        }

        return $this->render('index', [
            //'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'events' => $tasks,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Event model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Event model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate($date)
    {
        $model = new Event();
        $model->created_date = $date;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }else{
            return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Event model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else { 
            return $this->renderAjax('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Event model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Event model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Event the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Event::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }


    /**
 * 
 * @param type $choice
 * @return type
 */
    public function actionFilterEvents($choice = null) {
        Yii::$app->reponse->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $query = models\Event::find();

        if( is_null($choice) || $choice=='all'){
            //the function should return the same events that you were loading before
            $dbEvents = $query->all();
            $events = $this->loadEvents($dbEvents);
        } else{
            //here you need to look up into the data base 
            //for the relevant events against your choice
            $dbEvents = $query->where(['=', 'column_name', ':choice'])
                    ->params([':choice' => $choice])
                    ->asArray()
                    ->all();
            $events = $this->loadEvents($dbEvents);
        }
        return $events;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $dbEvents
     * @return \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event
     */
    private function loadEvents($dbEvents) {
        foreach( $dbEvents AS $event ){
            //Testing
            $Event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
            $Event->id = $event->id;
            $Event->title = $event->categoryAsString;
            $Event->description = $event->description;
            $Event->start = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($event->created_date . ' ' . $event->created_date));
            $Event->end = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($event->time_out . ' ' . $event->time_out));
            $Event->status = $event->status;
            $Event->remarks = $event->remarks;
            $events[] = $Event;
        }
        return $events;
    }
}
```

This is event-index :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

$this->title = 'Roster Bul Hanine Project';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$js=<<< JS
var eventSource=['/event/filter-events'];
$("#select_name").on('change',function() {
    //get current status of our filters into eventSourceNew
    var eventSourceNew=['/event/filter-events?choice=' +  $(this).val()];
    //remove the old eventSources
    $('#event').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource[0]);
    //attach the new eventSources
    $('#event').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSourceNew[0]);
    $('#event').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    //copy to current source 
    eventSource = eventSourceNew;
});
JS;
    $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);

?>
<div class="event-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p><?= Html::a('Create Roster', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?></p>
    <p>
        <select class="model_attribute" id="select_name">
            <option value="all">All Tech</option>
            <option value="0">Hendy Nugraha</option>
            <option value="1">Ginanjar Nurwin</option>
            <option value="2">Rio Andhika</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <div id="event"></div>

    <?php 
        Modal::begin([
            'header'=>'<h4>Roster</h4>',
            'id' => 'model',
            'size' => 'model-lg',
        ]);
        echo "<div id='modelContent'></div>";
        Modal::end();
    ?>

    <?=\yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
      'events'=> $events, 
      'id' => 'event',
      'clientOptions' => [ 
        'editable' => true,
        'eventSources' => ['/event/filter-events'],
        'draggable' => true,
        'droppable' => true,
        ],
      'eventClick' => "function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

                $.get('index.php?r=event/update',{'id':calEvent.id}, function(data){
                    $('.modal').modal('show')
                    .find('#modelContent')
                    .html(data);
                })

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (calEvent) {
                    return true;
                });

           }",

           /*$('#event').fullCalendar({
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                if(event.status == "on leave") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#131313');
                } else if (event.status == "stand by") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#678768');
                } else if (event.status == "active") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#554455');
                }
            },
        });*/
    ));

    ?>
</div>
```

***below is screen shot result when i comment 'events'=> $events, inside index.php, (as per your instruction). even I choose via select option, it's not filtering the event***

[image]

***if I un-comment 'events'=> $events, it's showing all events, but when i choose via select option, it's not filtering event. below the screen shot:***

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension you are using includes the latest version `FullCalendar v3.9.0`. So refer to the latest API version 3 for all the documentation references below.

#### Approach

To me, if I have to implement it I won't be using the `events` option as we need to filter events on runtime base on the option selected from the drop-down a better option would be to use `eventSources` option. It provides a way to specify multiple event sources. This option is used instead of the `events` option.You can put any number of [event arrays](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array), [functions](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function), [JSON feed URLs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed), or full-out [Event Source Objects](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object) into the `eventSources` array.

A simple example javascript based

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventSources: [
    '/feed1.php',
    '/feed2.php'
  ]
});
```

If you look into the documentation for Fullcalendar they have events related section with the name [`Event Data`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-data) where you can see various options along with the one mentioned.

#### Start From

We will start by providing `eventSources` a URL for our JSON feed for the calendar events, and remove the option `events`. I will use a single source you can have multiple too if you like but i will keep it short and simple.

Change the code for the Widget and add the `eventSources` option under the `clientOptions` option for the widget.

```
<?=
\yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
    'id' => 'eventFilterCalendar',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'editable' => true,
        'eventSources' => ['/schedule/filter-events'],
        'draggable' => true,
        'droppable' => true,
    ],
    'eventClick' => "function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        $.get('index.php?r=event/update',{'id':calEvent.id}, function(data){
            $('.modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modelContent')
            .html(data);
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (calEvent) {
            return true;
        });

    }",
));
?>
```

At this point if you will refresh the calendar you will not see any events that you were loading before because previously you were using the `'events'=>$events` to load the events but now we have provided a url source `'/schedule/filter-events'` (**change it to the relevant `controller/action` you want to use I will use the same URL for the example**).

#### Second Part

So the `$events` that you were loading before, will now have to load via the new action we are going to create. If you are following the example provided on the GitHub page for the extension and loading your events from the database model and then looping over with a for loop to load all of the events to the `\yii2fullcalendar\models\Events()` model and then load that array.

**As you have not provided any detail regarding the model you are using for the database to store and load events to the calendar, I assume that your model name is `MyEvents` change it accordingly and the field `column_name` in the query.**

```
/**
 * 
 * @param type $choice
 * @return type
 */
public function actionFilterEvents($choice = null) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $query = MyEvents::find();

    if( is_null($choice) || $choice=='all'){
        //the function should return the same events that you were loading before
        $dbEvents = $query->all();

    } else{
        //here you need to look up into the data base 
        //for the relevant events against your choice
        $dbEvents = $query->where(['=', 'column_name', ':choice'])
                ->params([':choice' => $choice])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
    }

    return $this->loadEvents($dbEvents);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param type $dbEvents
 * @return \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event
 */
private function loadEvents($dbEvents) {
    foreach( $dbEvents AS $event ){
        //Testing
        $Event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
        $Event->id = $event->id;
        $Event->title = $event->categoryAsString;
        $Event->start = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($event->date_start . ' ' . $event->time_start));
        $Event->end = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime($event->date_end . ' ' . $event->time_end));
        $events[] = $Event;
    }
    return $events;
}
```

Things to notice above

- `$choice` parameter in `actionFilterEvents` with `null` as the default value for listing all the events when the calendar loads for the first time.
- The `loadEvents()` method to load the searched events from the database to `\yii2fullcalendar\model\Events`, **do change the field names used in the `foreach` with the relevant model field names that you will use instead of `MyEvents`**.

At this point, if you have done everything correctly as mentioned if you refresh your page you will see the default events loading in the calendar.

#### Actual part

Now comes the part of filtering the events depending on the choice of the drop-down. For server-side we have already done the work above, the `else` part will handle filtering all the events from the database by comparing the selected choice with the desired column `column_name` (**replace it with the field name you want to compare with**).
The part still to be done is the client-side now, we will bind the `onchange` event of the dropdown and then use mainly these 3 `methods` provided by fullcalendar

- [`removeEventSource`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEventSource),Dynamically removes an event source.Events from the source will be immediately removed from the calendar.
- [`addEventSource`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/addEventSource),Dynamically adds an event source.The source may be an Array/URL/Function just as in the events option. Events will be immediately fetched from this source and placed on the calendar.
- [`refetchEvents`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/refetchEvents), Refetches events from all sources and rerenders them on the screen.

Every time we select a choice the previous `eventSource` is removed and a new `eventSource` is added so basically will building the url `schedule/filter-events?choice=all` if `All Tech` is selected, `schedule/filter-events?choice=0` if `Hendy Nugraha` is selected and so on.

Add the below javascript on top of your view where you have initialized your widget.

**Make sure the selector used below `#select_name` is matched with your drop-down's actual `id`.**

```
$js = <<< JS

        var eventSource=['/schedule/filter-events'];

        $("#select_name").on('change',function() {

        //get current status of our filters into eventSourceNew
        var eventSourceNew=['/schedule/filter-events?choice=' +  $(this).val()];

        //remove the old eventSources
        $('#eventFilterCalendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource[0]);
        //attach the new eventSources
        $('#eventFilterCalendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSourceNew[0]);
        $('#eventFilterCalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

        //copy to current source 
        eventSource = eventSourceNew;
    });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Do everything as told above and it will start working and will show you filtered results as soon as you change options in the drop-down.

***Note: I have provided the solution above from a running project, with `Yii2.0.15.1` and the latest available extension.***

#### EDIT

I am amazed that you can't differentiate between server-side, HTML and javascript, the code I provided related to javascript that you needed to paste in the view `event-index` was inside the [`heredoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and you had to just copy paste it but somehow you ended up wrapping the javascript inside the `<script>` tag and removed the `heredoc`? and moreover you are calling the `$this->registerJs()` inside the script tag rather than the `<?php ?>` tags ? **¯\_(ツ)_/¯**.

And you didn't even changed the controller name in the URL for the `var eventSource=['/schedule/filter-events'];` javascript code your controller is `Event` and not `schedule`, i wrote at every point where i assumed a model or controller name to change it accordingly, even your widget code is not updated accordingly it also has the `'eventSources' => ['/schedule/filter-events'],` when it should be `'eventSources' => ['/event/filter-events'],`.

So this time just copy paste the whole view code below and **DO NOT CHANGE** anything. I won't be spoon feeding you anymore just because you have to mark it correct, although it is the correct answer and should Have been awarded the  Bounty.

**Troubleshooting and fixing syntax errors are your duties to fix along when you are integrating the code. The solution provided is working and you failing to integrate it does not mean it isnt the correct answer.**

'event-index.php`

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

$this->title = 'Roster Bul Hanine Project';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$js=<<< JS
var eventSource=['/event/filter-events'];
$("#select_name").on('change',function() {
    //get current status of our filters into eventSourceNew
    var eventSourceNew=['/event/filter-events?choice=' +  $(this).val()];
    //remove the old eventSources
    $('#event').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventSource[0]);
    //attach the new eventSources
    $('#event').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSourceNew[0]);
    $('#event').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    //copy to current source 
    eventSource = eventSourceNew;
});
JS;
    $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);

?>
<div class="event-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p><?= Html::a('Create Roster', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?></p>
    <p>
        <select class="model_attribute" id="select_name">
            <option value="all">All Tech</option>
            <option value="0">Hendy Nugraha</option>
            <option value="1">Ginanjar Nurwin</option>
            <option value="2">Rio Andhika</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <div id="event"></div>



    <?php 
        Modal::begin([
            'header'=>'<h4>Roster</h4>',
            'id' => 'model',
            'size' => 'model-lg',
        ]);
        echo "<div id='modelContent'></div>";
        Modal::end();

    ?>

    <?=\yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
      //'events'=> $events, 
      'id' => 'event',
      'clientOptions' => [ 
        'editable' => true,
        'eventSources' => ['/event/filter-events'],
        'draggable' => true,
        'droppable' => true,
        ],
      'eventClick' => "function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

                $.get('index.php?r=event/update',{'id':calEvent.id}, function(data){
                    $('.modal').modal('show')
                    .find('#modelContent')
                    .html(data);
                })

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (calEvent) {
                    return true;
                });

           }",

           /*$('#event').fullCalendar({
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                if(event.status == "on leave") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#131313');
                } else if (event.status == "stand by") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#678768');
                } else if (event.status == "active") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#554455');
                }
            },
        });*/
    ));

    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Muhammad, sorry for late reply. fyi, i just edited my codes above (adding models/Event.php & models/EventSearch.php). For right now i'm still create new table inside phpmyadmin database, not JSON.  to be honest, I still need your assist, but sorry for asking stupid question, where should I put your codes in Second Part "actionFilterEvents" & "loadEvents($dbEvents)" function? I assume it should be inside models/Event.php, not in models/EventSearch.php right ?. and for the Actual Part codes, I assume it should be put inside main.js right?

Comment: basically, i just want to implement a very basic filtering events in this Full Calendar plugin using phpmyadmin database

Comment: the above-given functions should be inside your controller not model, you can choose any controller you like, better you should choose the controller via which you are loading the calendar-view/widget, and replace the `MyEvents` model in the code with `models\Events`, i hope you get where you need to add the code in . @Hendy

Comment: about the javascript, you should add it on top of the view `event-index ` where you are rendering the widget @Hendy